# Get observer of NSNotification in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have a static method in a separate class to handle UIKeyboard.`WillHideNotification` & `UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification` so that it can be used across the app.

I am adding the observer in a ViewController in the following way :-

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver (UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, KeyboardAppearanceUtilities.OnKeyboardNotification);
```

How can I get the observer object in the notification Action method which is declared in `KeyboardAppearanceUtilities` class as follows :-

```
public static void OnKeyboardNotification (NSNotification notification)
{

}
```

notification.Object is always null for obvious reason that I am not setting the object parameter in the `AddObserver` method.

Can someone guide me how to rearrange the code so that this notification handler can be used across the app and also gives me access to the observer?

Comment: the observer in this case is your `OnKeyboardNotification()` method. Do you mean the sender? That should be the UIWindow the keyboard is shown in, so in most cases just the only app window.

Comment: Yes the observer being the OnKeyboardNotification method, how can I access the sender in that method? notification.Object is null.

Comment: If notification.object is null, then the notification was probably posted without specifying the object. But in this case, why do you need to access the sender?

Comment: I just checked the documentation for these notifications, the object is nil by design: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-SW18

Comment: @StefanFisk I want to make this method resuable by any UITextField across all viewcontrollers in the app. So I thought of putting it into a separate static class and call that method from all my UIViewControllers wherever UITextFields are present and handle them accordingly. So I want to know the sender of specific notificaion ie., specific UIView or UIViewController

Comment: The notification is sent by the window, so generalizing might be hard. What behavior is it that you want to be able to share for all control types?

Comment: @StefanFisk I am updating the Frame of the UIView in keyboard appearance/disappearance. And I want to adjust the height by which I move up/down based on the UIView that is sending this notification.

Comment: I'd say observe the notification in the view controller, and when it is posted check which control is the first responder, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would be a lot nicer if you used the strongly typed notifications:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIKeyboard%2bNotifications.ObserveWillHide

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can get the view that is the firstResponder ie., the UITextField that is the cause of the keyboard appearance? My plan is - If I get the view that is the cause of this, I can as well get the root View of the viewcontroller and then adjust the root view's frame up/down. The sender object is null when i applied the code in the link u shared.